# Android - remove all app, except settings and custom app

Tags: android, react-native, nexus-7

I am working on a project where I am developing mobile app (android) using react native. The development of the app is fine. However, I need to remove all other apps from the existing device (I am using Nexus 7) but except `settings` and my app (the one that I am developing).

This special requirements is a `must` have as the device will be giving to the customer for one purpose only. So I need to have only one app installed and disable any option to installed any other apps from the app store.

But I have no idea, how I might be able to do so. So I really need your help. If you could guide me on this, would mean the world to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't remove the standard applications because they are stored in flash memory (OS image) and this memory is readonly. What you can do is to download entire android, build own image stripping all the unnecessary services, applications, etc. And then flash this new image to the device. The process is not sample and straight.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply mate. Can you give me some suggestions on how I can get started with this. I really have no idea. Googling is taking me so many different pages, I am so confused.

Comment: @jahid, you can start reading this forum: https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7

Comment: I have studied little bit from this above source. Seems very complicated. Still its good place to start so I am accepting this as an answer.